# Should I use class based or function based views for this?

Tags: python, django

This will be a long post so bear with me. I think I came to the realization that I have to re-write a lot of code that I previously wrote in my models.

my models look like this:

```
class Word(models.Model):
    '''Word table for word, and frequency data'''

    language = models.ForeignKey(Language)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    frequency = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    rank = models.IntegerField(default=0)


    def __unicode__(self):
        value = u'%s' % (self.name)
        return value


    def wn_lookup(self):
        '''Calls the wordnet CLI for self'''    
        ...breaks up the output and returns the definitions as a list of tuples

    def wiktionary_lookup(self, wiktionary_prefix, driver):
        ...looks up the definition of the word on wiktionary
           returns data as a list

    def define(self, driver, choice, ask_input):
        ...Prints out a lot of options and asks the user to choose 
           what they want as a definition

           It then creates objects and calls other methods on a 
           subsequent definitions model
```

Note that the last method creates and calls methods of a subsequent definitions model.

I have a few models, all with methods that require a lot of user input to semi-automate the data entry. I believe I have done this stupidly and I should actually add them in the views, but I am a bit confused about how to do that.

1. Should I use a class based or function based view?
2. I guess I have to actually write forms and templates for all of these views?
3. Is it possible that I should leave everything where it is (in models) and not put it in views?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can use what you want, the benefit of [Class Based Views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/class-based-views/) is inheritance. You can extend your base `View` class and use it throughout your project. Also, it's quite fast to get operations working with [Generic Class Based Views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#built-in-class-based-generic-views).
2. Yes you should write a form for this model, to provide user input. Django provides shortcuts for forms, which save data based on a model. [Model Forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform) automatically map all fields in your model with equivelent form fields.
3. Django follows a pattern called `Fat Models` so it is completely fine to store operations for a model within its model definition.